# How to play an MKV 3D side-by-side video?

Tags: hdvideo, matroska

I have a video in [Matroska format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) (MKV, file extension `.mkv`), 3D half-SBS, where the 1280x720 frame shows the left-eye frame on the left and the right-eye frame on the right.

I don't have a [3DTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_television), but I have NVidia 3D Vision: I tried to open it with [PowerDVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerDVD) 10 with no result (program hangs). With the same PowerDVD, I tried to play the Avatar 3D trailer downloaded from YouTube ([MP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) format), but it now shows it the two frames.

PowerDVD 10 is advertised to support 3D and 3D Vision. Why can't I play these videos?

NVidia Stereoscopic player plays the Avatar trailer fine, but it doesn't support MKV.

Comment: why you are converting mkv to vob? you all lose resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to install K-Lite codec pack and use 3D Vision player to play the files! You must select a proper splitter for Matroska. In my case, FLV splitter worked fine!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

PowerDVD 10 Ultra Mark II should be able to play 3D half-SBS MKV files. Did you try enabling 3D by clicking on the "3D button"?

I have had better luck with [Stereoscopic Player](http://3dtv.at/products/Player/Index_de.aspx) when it comes to 3D MKV files. If Stereoscopic Player fails to play the file, try installing [K-Lite Codec Standard Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_standard.htm).

Comment: That is the PowerDVD version I have. It hangs when trying to play MKV. Trying K-Lite

Comment: I DID IT!!!!!!!! K-Lite solved the problem, but I had to enable the AVI splitter in Stereo Player manually, probably because I have installed it prior to the codecs :)

Answer (score 3):

Bino 3D supports playing MKV, and is free+open source:

http://bino3d.org/download.html

Comment: Hi, Bino doesn't support NVidia 3D Vision, which is what I wanted. Anyway it looks great with Discover or native TV that play SBS

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I tried playing the half side-by-side MKV on my Samsung 51" plasma which is 3D enabled.

However when I converted the file to .VOB keeping all parameters intact, the 3D played like heaven.