# Playing 3D mkv on 3D TV

Tags: matroska, 3d

I just bought a brand new LG 42LW4500 TV with enabled 3D think its passive any how i have an option to convert 2D > 3D i also got a full set of normal 3D Glases.

Now today i downloaded a 3D movie (14GB) Full HD in a mkv format i hooked up my PC to my TV and opened the mkv in VLC player and what i got was 2 pictures in one screen sowing same thing. Now i am lost from here i enabled 3D but it didnt really feel like 3D.

Can anyone shed some ligth on how can you play 3D movies do i need to use 2D > 3D conversion on tv or?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play an MKV 3D side-by-side video?](http://superuser.com/questions/205289/how-to-play-an-mkv-3d-side-by-side-video)

Comment: Not really the guy did not have a 3D TV and wanted to know how to play a SBS video. My problem is diff.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.3dtv.at/Index_en.aspx with proper video card driver that can do HDMI 1.4 out is what you need.  See: http://www.makemkv.com/forum2/viewtopic.php?t=4781

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.