# duplicate scene playing mkv file in kmplayer

Tags: video, kmplayer

I have downloaded a video file with `.mkv` extension. This is the file's properties:

[image]

When I play it using `kmplayer`, it has double scene effect like this:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play an MKV 3D side-by-side video?](http://superuser.com/questions/205289/how-to-play-an-mkv-3d-side-by-side-video)

Comment: No @FiveO, I want to remove this effect.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I have the same problem, more than 3 years later.

Comment: Dear @Stefan, unfortunately no! If you can ever solve it, please let me know.

Comment: @Zeinab Abbasimazar I finally found a solution that worked for me, which I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

If your KMPlayer is Updated:
1.Right click on the screen. A list of options appears.
2.Goto 3D Screen Controls in those options.
3.Select " Side by Side -> 2D ".

Answer (score 1):

In VLC this can be done by cropping one side of a video. Effects - video - crop right or left 960 pixels if a video is 1920 pixels wide. (1920/2=960).
Then you force aspect ratio 32:9 (instead of 16:9; 16x2=32) in preferences-video.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Thank you very much for trying to contribute to this site, but the given question has already been answered very detailed, and your answer doesn’t provide more additional help.

Answer (score 0):

You are watching a 3D movie in 2D. In order to watch 3D movies you must have 3D capable hardware, and use a 3D capable software. There are programs for converting 3D movies to 2D (which would get rid of the side-by-side effect), but as I've never used any I can't recommend one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try some of such applications and let you know about the result.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that worked for me, using VLC Video Player.

The idea is to crop the right side image away, and to set a new custom aspect ratio.

I suspect KMPlayer also has facilities for cropping and setting custom aspect ratios?

The crop and aspect ratio settings below worked for a 1920 x 816 video. You might need to adjust these, depending on your particular specifications.

Here are the steps, in VLC:

**First, set a new custom aspect ratio:**

1. Open VLC.
2. Go to Tools -> Preferences -> (Show all settings, for some versions) -> Videos.
   Enter a custom aspect ratio of 32:9.  Click 'Save'.

**Now, crop the screen:**

3. Restart VLC.
4. Go to Tools -> Effects & Filters -> Video Effects -> Crop.
   Crop 960 px on the right (this is equal to half the screen width, i.e. 1920/2)

**Check the aspect ratio:**

5. Make sure Video->Aspect Ratio has 32:9 as the selected ratio.

The video should now play without the mirrored image.

When you play other 'normal' videos again, you will have to remove the custom aspect ratio setting, by following steps 1 & 2, but this time remove the custom ratio you set previously and click 'Save'.